# MySQL Join Inconsistent Performance Depending on WHERE

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have a query that is taking several seconds to complete for certain WHERE conditions. To the best of my knowledge, everything is indexed correctly, but performance is still poor. All tables are InnoDB, blog_users and blog_users_profiles contain about 5 million rows and forum_contacts has about 10K rows.

The query

```
SELECT blog.*
FROM blog_users AS blog
INNER JOIN blog_user_profiles AS profile ON blog.user_id = profile.user_id
INNER JOIN forum_contacts AS contact ON profile.forum_id = contact.user_id
WHERE blog.comments > :comment_cutoff
AND blog.last_active > :time_cutoff
AND contact.type = :contact_type
AND contact.area = :location
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Explain output

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys                | key       | key_len | ref                          | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | blog    | range  | PRIMARY,last_active,comments | comments  | 3       | NULL                         | 1313813 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | profile | eq_ref | PRIMARY,forum_id             | PRIMARY   | 3       | xc_db.blog.user_id           |       1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contact | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type,area,user_id    | PRIMARY   | 80      | xc_db.profile.forum_id,const |       1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Table structure (irrelevant rows snipped)

blog_users

```
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id     | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username    | varchar(16)           | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| comments    | mediumint(7) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| last_active | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

blog_user_profiles

```
+----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id  | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| forum_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
+----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

forum_contacts

```
+---------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| type    | varchar(25)           | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| area    | varchar(255)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The strange thing is that the execution time seems to be inversely related to the total number of rows returned. For example, a query like contact.area = 'United States' which returns a few thousand rows executes in less than 0.01 second. However, queries with fewer result rows such as contact.area = 'Egypt' which returns 20 rows takes in excess of 5 seconds to complete. Does my query need to be rewritten or is there a problem with the indexes?

Comment: The problem with LIMIT is that results will not be cached in the query cache. So the next time you do something like LIMIT 101,200 the query will be executed again. A possible workaround would be storing the results of your query in a temporary table and then run your queries with LIMIT on that temporary table.

Comment: I think you're right that it has something to do with the LIMIT. On the Egypt query if I do LIMIT 0, 20 (the same as the number of results) it takes about half a second, but if I raise it to LIMIT 0, 21 it takes several seconds.